# Runtimeerror: Event loop is closed - asyncio, aiohttp, concurrent request

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am very new to async programming. Environment- Win11,Python 3.10.5. I am trying to make concurrent requests and obtain the results in a list simply. I've tried going through the suggestions on stackoverflow to troubleshoot the issue but couldn't get what exactly is causing it. Though I can see the result, still getting the Runtimeerror: Event loop is closed. Here is my code

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time

names = ["rahul"]*4

def get_tasks(session):
    tasks = []
    for name in names:
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(session.get(url =f"https://api.agify.io?name={name}", ssl=False)))
    return tasks

async def my_f2():
    result = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = get_tasks(session)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks,return_exceptions=True)
        #print(responses)
        for response in responses:
            result.append(await response.json())
    # print(result)
    return result

start = time.time()
result = asyncio.run(my_f2())
print(result)
end = time.time()
print(f"Total time : {end-start}")
```

This is the exception raised with the output that shows the result list

> [{'name': 'rahul', 'age': 38, 'count': 9575}, {'name': 'rahul', 'age':
> 38, 'count': 9575}, {'name': 'rahul', 'age': 38, 'count': 9575},
> {'name': 'rahul', 'age': 38, 'count': 9575}] Total time :
> 0.9891138076782227 Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.**del** at 0x00000234477E25F0> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Dipankar
> Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py",
> line 116, in **del**
> self.close()   File "C:\Users\Dipankar Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py",
> line 108, in close
> self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)   File "C:\Users\Dipankar
> Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 750, in call_soon
> self._check_closed()   File "C:\Users\Dipankar Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 515, in _check_closed
> raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed') RuntimeError: Event loop is closed Exception ignored in: <function
> _ProactorBasePipeTransport.**del** at 0x00000234477E25F0> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Dipankar
> Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py",
> line 116, in **del**
> self.close()   File "C:\Users\Dipankar Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py",
> line 108, in close
> self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)   File "C:\Users\Dipankar
> Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 750, in call_soon
> self._check_closed()   File "C:\Users\Dipankar Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 515, in _check_closed
> raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed') RuntimeError: Event loop is closed Exception ignored in: <function
> _ProactorBasePipeTransport.**del** at 0x00000234477E25F0> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Dipankar
> Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py",
> line 116, in **del**
> self.close()   File "C:\Users\Dipankar Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py",
> line 108, in close
> self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)   File "C:\Users\Dipankar
> Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 750, in call_soon
> self._check_closed()   File "C:\Users\Dipankar Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 515, in _check_closed
> raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed') RuntimeError: Event loop is closed Exception ignored in: <function
> _ProactorBasePipeTransport.**del** at 0x00000234477E25F0> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Dipankar
> Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py",
> line 116, in **del**
> self.close()   File "C:\Users\Dipankar Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py",
> line 108, in close
> self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)   File "C:\Users\Dipankar
> Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 750, in call_soon
> self._check_closed()   File "C:\Users\Dipankar Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 515, in _check_closed
> raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed') RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Comment: What version of aiohttp are you using? A believe 3.8+ is required for Python 3.10.

Comment: @dirn I'm using aiohttp==3.8.1